# Badwords - stop users to bypass the bad word filter in php

Tags: php, regex

I use a badwordfilter array to prevent badwords in user generated content.

Example of badwords:

```
$badwords = array ( 1 => 'adult', 2 => 'porn' )
```

**Problem:**

The users try always to avoid the badword filter with dots, commas or other charakters like *!?#

**Example:**

```
a.dult
po,rn
```

Is it anyways possible, to check the string / badwords for a list of chars (.,?!) and if a word is found, where one of this chars is inside, give a error message?

```
"Don´t bypass the badword filter".
```

Thank you very much for your time.

I know there are many ways to bypass a badword filter but its enough to check a string for words that have a dot or comma inside.

Comment: Strip out everything but letters and spaces and check for bad words.  If none found then use the original.  However, bad word filters are not that accurate.  `adult` can be used legitimately can't it?  Also, if you block `ass` what about `association`?

Comment: Problem is that you can also use p0rn - not that I ever have :-/

Comment: I know that a wordfilter is never 100%. For the replacement I use a other array. At the moment I try only to stop the users doin this.

Comment: Cl***ic and con****uous issue of the [S****horpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to bybass the badwords but for me it would be ok to check a string for words that have a dot or a comma inside

Comment: What about `aduult`?

Comment: `preg_replace` `/[^a-z ]/i` with `''` then check it.

Comment: @AbraCadaver what about `aduult` or `p0rn`?

Comment: I dont care about aduult. 99% of the users try it with dots or commas. When they first time see the error message, they will not try different versions.

Comment: @ctwheels They/I are just concentrating on non aplha such as punctuation and special chars.

Comment: @AbraCadaver it would be great to give me a piece of code. I think I have to explode the string first, then check every word for special chars inside?

Comment: What in the hell is a _bad_ word? And obfuscated? Must be a kindergarten website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex**: `\b` (badword) `\b` and `[.,?!]`

Details:

- `\b` Assert position at a word boundary
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list

**PHP code**:

```
$str = 'bla bla p.orn, bla bla a.dult bla bla association';

$bad_words = array('adult', 'porn', 'ass');
$reg = '~\b' . implode('\b|\b', $bad_words) . '\b~';

preg_match_all($reg, preg_replace('~[.,?!]~', '', $str), $matches);

if(count($matches[0]) > 0)
    echo '"Don´t bypass the badword filter".';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => porn
    [1] => adult
)
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/J0KIG9)

Comment: wow, this is very smart @S.Jovan. Is it possible to echo a error message also, when there is a dot inside of a badword or inside a word from the string?

Comment: Thank you. Its almost perfect. When when you remove the dots in the string, it gives the error message also?

Comment: @labu77 I don't get any error messeges when i remove dotes... See it for you self [code demo](https://ideone.com/l1Oks3)

Comment: I see "Don´t bypass the badword filter". on  stdout

Comment: I have php 5.6. could this be the reason? it would be very kind to give me a code for 5.6 also.

Comment: @labu77 Maybe, I don't know. I am using PHP 7.1.0 and I don't get any 'PHP errors'. My code is capturing bad words with and without dot, comma...

Comment: see https://ideone.com/fGtfhx  inside the array are adult and porn. so matches = 2

Comment: @labu77 There are still bad words in that string. So, if you remove them you wont get an 'error'.

Comment: ok I see. the words will be replaced automaticly. is it possible to give the error message only when there is a .,?! inside? thank you very much for your time

Comment: @labu77 No. We remove chars `.,?!` from the string, then match the bad words and if array has more then 0 matches it will echo 'error'.

Comment: after final testing I like your code very much and gave you the green arrow. When I will find some further improvements with the code, is it ok for you to post it here?

Comment: @labu77 No problem, I don't mind. Paste the code [here](https://ideone.com/) and send it to me.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not case sensitiv, i can still write bad words with uppercase. It wont get replaced.

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a function using the [**`Levenshtein` distance**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php):

```
<?php

$data = 'bla bla p.orn, bla bla a.dult bla bla association';

function filter($string) {
    $badwords = array('adult', 'porn', 'ass');
    $words = array_unique(preg_split("~\s+~", $string));
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        foreach ($badwords as $bad) {
            if (levenshtein($word, $bad) <= 1) {
                return ["result" => false, "word" => $word];
            }
        }
    }
    return ["result" => true, "word" => null];
}

$f = filter($data);
if ($f["result"] === false) {
    echo "Please don't use {$f["word"]}\n";
}
?>
```

This splits the "words" (a word is considered separated by whitespaces) and calculates the distance to every word in the bad word list.
This is by far not the fastest approach but considers `porn` to be the same as `p0rn` or `p$rn`. A distance of 0 is essentially the same word, here you'll surely need some tweaking.

Comment: wow, this is also incredible smart. thank you so much @jan. I will test all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table in MySQL with a list of excluded words in it, you can run a query like the following:

```
SELECT word, COUNT(word) AS matches 
FROM badwords 
WHERE LOWER('User input string goes here after processing') LIKE CONCAT('%', word, '%') 
GROUP BY word
```

This will return a list of excluded words with their counts.

The processing I speak of can be as simple as:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $input)
```

to remove all special characters, or you could try to replace characters with their expected replacements, such as o for 0 and the like. It is a substitution complexity war against people who are creative with ASCII. Not really a war that is winnable, but you can mitigate the common options.

Comment: I will give them a try. I have to create a table first. thank you